# Trouble with tables containing images

Tags: html, image

If I insert an image into a table, then the contents of all other cells on that row are shifted down below the level of the image, even when the image is much smaller than its cell. How do I correct this?

Comment: Please post your example code.

Comment: FOUND IT!    I neglected to override a vertical-align command in my CSS reset.